# Drupal 7 Users/Roles - Create a series of roles that encompass other roles

Tags: drupal, permissions, roles, account

This is my first experience building a site with Drupal and am still learning about all I can do with it.

I am trying to figure out a way to configure sort of a second level of user roles consisting of roles defined with permissions. The users of the site will be group members with various titles, for example: Manager, secretary, web admin, etc. Each of these titles will have responsibilities within the site. The users tied to these titles change though and I would like re-configuring this in the site to be as easy as possible (will be for someone unfamiliar with Drupal).

I am thinking configure permissions into roles such as content editor, file uploader, etc based around the responsibilities each title will have. Then I would need an additional role editing page (probably custom) that would show a similar table to permissions/roles but would be with roles/titles where the site admin could easily take a person with say secretary title and easily provide them the ability to edit dates, or upload files, etc.

This would make it easy in that the site admin would only be presented with the titles and the abilities defined for site usage, and not have to comb through the entire list of permissions.

The second issue with this would be then how do I assign titles to users. Ideally it would be the same as assigning roles within a users account page.

Any suggestions/ideas?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The more Drupal-ish way to handle this is to just make your individual roles ("content editor", "file uploader") into the roles and assign multiple roles per user. So instead of there for example being a "Manager" title which gets the "content editor" and "file uploader" roles, you would just assign those two roles to users directly and avoid the notion of the "manager" title altogether.

The other obvious option is to just make your titles the roles, meaning that the "manager" role gets all the permissions that would otherwise be given to "content editor" and "file uploader".

Both of those methods avoid the notion of two levels of roles and since that's not really how Drupal is supposed to work, it will save you lots of pain to go this route.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand what you are explaining and currently have it set up the way you describe. I would like to set up the role management system in way I describe because when I am finished the site administrator will not be knowledgeable in Drupal or web design and will need to easily provide users titles and those titles roles.